# is not an enclosing class / new Intent Cannot Resolve Constructor

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent, onclicklistener

Thanks for checking out my question!

I have a relativly ismple loop which will add a onClickListener to each ImageView I add to my Layout, however when trying to add a new Intent to it, it gives me one of the following errors:

```
    String[] imageURLs = imageURLsString.split("/");
    for (int i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++){
        ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
        image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(getPx(182),getPx(256)));
        image.setPadding(getPx(3),getPx(3),getPx(3),getPx(3));
        final String imageURL = ".../images/" + imageURLs[i];
        Picasso.with(this).load(imageURL).into(image);

        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent;
                intent = new Intent(this, ImageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("URL", imageURL);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        linearLayout.addView(image);
    }
```

Will result in the "Cannot resolve Constructor 'Intent ...." error.
So when I was looking for a solution, people suggested to change "this" to "MainActivity.this", but...

```
    String[] imageURLs = imageURLsString.split("/");
    for (int i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++){
        ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
        image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(getPx(182),getPx(256)));
        image.setPadding(getPx(3),getPx(3),getPx(3),getPx(3));
        final String imageURL = ".../images/" + imageURLs[i];
        Picasso.with(this).load(imageURL).into(image);

        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent;
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("URL", imageURL);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        linearLayout.addView(image);
    }
```

resulted into: com.myName.appName.MainActivity is not an enclosing class

Here is the ImageActivity class:

```
public class ImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);

        String URL = getIntent().getExtras().getString("URL");

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (imageView.getLayoutParams().width * (Float.valueOf(String.valueOf(1.41))));
        Picasso.with(this).load(URL).into(imageView);
    }
```

The weird thing is that I have done numerous new Intent's during my play time with creating apps, but I cant seem to solve this one. What am I missing here?

FULL CODE FROM HERE

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView TVWeChatIdValue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        String dataString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataString");
        String[] itemData = dataString.split(",");
        String category = itemData[0];
        Log.e("DetailsActivity", category);
        String itemID = itemData[1];
        Log.e("DetailsActivity", itemID);
        String imageURLsString = itemData[2];
        Log.e("DetailsActivity", imageURLsString);
        String description = itemData[3];
        Log.e("DetailsActivity", description);
        String price = itemData[4];
        Log.e("DetailsActivity", price);

        String itemCode = category + itemID;

        TextView textView;
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Title);
        textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ItemReferralValue);
        textView.setText(itemCode);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ItemPriceValue);
        textView.setText(price);

        TVWeChatIdValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WeChatIDValue);
        new DatabaseTask(this, "details", "GETWECHATID").execute();

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ItemDetailsContent);

        String[] imageURLs = imageURLsString.split("/");
        for (int i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++){
            ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
            image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(getPx(182),getPx(256)));
            image.setPadding(getPx(3),getPx(3),getPx(3),getPx(3));
            final String imageURL = ".../images/" + imageURLs[i];
            Picasso.with(this).load(imageURL).into(image);

            image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent;
                    intent = new Intent(this, ImageActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("URL", imageURL);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            linearLayout.addView(image);
        }

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ItemDetailsDescription);
        String imageURL = ".../images/" + description;
        Picasso.with(this).load(imageURL).into(imageView);

    }

    public void SetWeChatId(String mValue) {
        TVWeChatIdValue.setText(mValue);
    }

    public int getPx(int dimensionDp) {
        float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return (int) (dimensionDp * density + 0.5f);
    }
}
```

WORKING CODE

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView TVWeChatIdValue;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView;
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Title);
        textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SubTitle);
        textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.slogan));

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MoreForWomen);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                OpenCatalog("women");
            }
        });
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MoreForMen);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                OpenCatalog("men");
            }
        });
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MoreForKids);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                OpenCatalog("kids");
            }
        });
    }

    public void GetData() {
            TVWeChatIdValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WeChatIDValue);
            new DatabaseTask(this, "main", "GETWECHATID").execute();

            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.NewItemsForWomenContent);
            linearLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            new DatabaseTask(this, linearLayout, "WOMEN", "GETNEWESTITEMS").execute();
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.NewItemsForMenContent);
            linearLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            new DatabaseTask(this, linearLayout, "MEN", "GETNEWESTITEMS").execute();
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.NewItemsForKidsContent);
            linearLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            new DatabaseTask(this, linearLayout, "KIDS", "GETNEWESTITEMS").execute();
    }

    public void SetWeChatId(String mValue) {
        TVWeChatIdValue.setText(mValue);
    }

    public void ProcessNewItems(LinearLayout mLinearLayout, final String mCategory, final HashMap<Integer, Item> mItems){
        for (int i = 0; i < mItems.size(); i++) {
            ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
            image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(getPx(96),getPx(128)));
            image.setPadding(getPx(3),getPx(3),getPx(3),getPx(3));
            String imageURL = ".../images/" + mItems.get(i).getImageURLs()[0];
            Picasso.with(this).load(imageURL).into(image);

            mLinearLayout.addView(image);
            final int index = i;
            image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ShowItemDetails(mCategory, mItems.get(index));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    void ShowItemDetails(String mCategory, Item mItem){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("dataString", mItem.GetDataString());
        Log.e("CatalogActivity", mItem.GetDataString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    void OpenCatalog(String mCategory){
        //show catalog
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CatalogActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("category", mCategory);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public int getPx(int dimensionDp) {
        float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return (int) (dimensionDp * density + 0.5f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        GetData();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the entire error message. By truncating, you potentially leave out information we need to help you. Also, remember in Java, all executable code belongs in a method in a class. In particular, what class and method contains the code which sets the `onClickListener()`? Giving us this context helps us understand your code snippets better.

Comment: Hi @Code-Apprentice, thanks for your reply. I have added the full code in the OP. I have also tried taking it out of OnCreate and doing the setting of the onClickListener in another method, but again without succes.

Comment: You should edit the original code snippets so that they are inside a method inside a class just as you would in a .java file. The code you added has many lines which are irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Also, if you need additional help, you to provide more detail than "without success".

Comment: Indeed, I should have said it gave the same result as the previous attempts. sorry for that! I will take note of your advice for future posts as well.

Comment: On a side note, the `mCategory` parameter of `ShowItemDetails()` is never used and should be removed.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that the moment I copied the code to post here. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the name of the `Activity` subclass which contains the code that creates the `OnClickListener`. In many examples, this is `MainActivity`. However, this doesn't seem to be the case in your code. Since you are in a class named `DetailsActivity` then use that name:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DetailsActivity.this, ImageActivity.class);
```

From what I can see of your code here, I strongly suggest that you learn about `ListView` and `RecyclerView`. They are a bit complex, but once you understand them, they do much of the work for you similar to what you are trying to do here. For one thing, they are more efficient than your own code because they only create as many views as are visible.

Let's look more closely at your other example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
    // ...
    void ShowItemDetails(String mCategory, Item mItem){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("dataString", mItem.GetDataString());
        startActivity(intent);
     }
}
```

Notice that the `ShowItemDetails()` is inside the `MainActivity` class. So `this` refers to an instance of that class which can be used wherever a `Context` is needed. (For more details about this you need to read about inheritance and polymorphism.)

On the other hand, your original code creates an `Intent` in a method which is inside an anonymous subclass of `OnClickListener` which cannot be used as a `Context`. However the anonymous inner class is in a method inside `DetailsActivity` which inherits from `Context`. In order to access an instance of this outer class, you have to use `DetailsActivity.this`.

For more details you should learn about the special `this` reference and inner classes.

Comment: I am not using any fragments or other special things. This was placed in the OnCreate method. See the full code in the OP. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, that did the job! I have added a class to the OP that worked the way I tried it before by calling a method to set the onClickListener instead of doing in the OnCreate method. In there I didnt had to set the class before "this". Can you explain me where the difference is? Again many thanks!

Comment: Also, I do know how to work with ListViews, ScrollViews, Grids and creating Custom Adapters, but I was experimenting with some new things. I like to learn new things by trail and error hehe =)

Comment: @sdieters See my most recent edit for a more detailed explanation. Experimentation is a great way to learn. Good luck!

Comment: I see, this makes total sense now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You have this block

```
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("URL", imageURL);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Change `MainActivity.this` to whatever `Activity` subclass that is setting the `OnClickListener`. That would be `DetailsActivity.this` in your case. Basically the enclosing activity just means the name of the class file (which is also the name of the `Activity` class) in which the `Activity` is being defined, this `Activity` encapsulates the call to `.setOnClickListener()` to which you are passing an anonymous inner class, which is being *enclosed* inside your `DetailsActivity`, hence the name enclosing activity. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Already tried that, but I cannot seem to figure out what the Enclosing Activity should be in my case. The full code is now in the OP. Thanks!